# What are .o.d files used for?

Tags: c++, netbeans

I use netbeans and notice that in addition to creating the .o files, it also creates .o.d files. What are these files (.o.d) for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described by [Netbeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/cnd/depchecking.html): Dependency files.

Build systems try to make it so that if you recompile, you save effort by not recompiling translation units whose generated object file will be identical. So it only attempts to recompile files that have changed, or files that maybe haven't changed but a file they depend on has changed. The `.o.d` files track which files the `.o` depends on so that it can quickly determine what needs to be recompiled if you build your project again.